# How to duplicate range in Word without clipboard in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and this code to duplicate section of `Word` document using `C#`:

```
var R1 = FindRange(Document);
R1.Copy();
var R2 = Document.Range(R1.End, R1.End);
R2.Paste();
```

The range section contains various elements like paragraphs and tables.
This code essentially copy/pastes the section of document and works fine.

Is there any other way to achieve same result without using `Copy()` and `Paste()` functions as they use clipboard (which is big problem)?

Comment: If the Clipboard is a security problem, why don´t you CLEAR it immediately after the copy/paste?  I believe you cannot transfer, easily, data between 2 WORD docs without copy/paste.

Comment: @DavidBS Using the clipboard for programming is unquestionably bad programming practice. Not merely a security issue.

Comment: @David BS: It is not a security problem in the first line. Some other application could put something on clipboard while I am working with the document and cause error or unpredictable result - that is the problem.
Also, I am NOT USING TWO documents but ONLY ONE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that using the clipboard is a bad idea.

Here's an example based on XML that copies the contents of the bookmark named "bookmark" in a source document named "Document2" to the current `Selection` range.

```
void XmlDemo()
{
    var wordApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    var docSource = wordApp.Documents["Document2"];

    var rngTarget = wordApp.Selection.Range;
    var rngSource = docSource.Bookmarks["bookmark"].Range;

    rngTarget.InsertXML(rngSource.XML);
}
```

I'm unaware of its limitations, but I just tested it to copy some text, a table and a shape without any hassle.

### Alternative

As specified in the comments below, and alternative is to use the [FormattedText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213159(v=office.11).aspx) property of the `Range`:

```
R2.FormattedText = R1.FormattedText;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Meanwhile, I found the solution, it seems that simply assigning `R2.FormattedText = R1.FormattedText;` works perfectly, copies everything inside.
Please add `R2.FormattedText = R1.FormattedText;` as another alternative to your code and I will accept the answer.

Comment: @Dusan That's an interesting solution. I bet there's a difference, although I don't know what exactly. Thank you - answer updated.

Comment: @DanL The limitation of the approach you propose is that the XML property will only support features available in Word 2003. It works with the 2003 WordProcessingML, not WordOpenXML. There is the Range.WordOpenXML property which might work in most situations. There are things in Word, though, that aren't picked up by it and included in the OPC flat file format. Range.FormattedText is the "accepted" approach for the original question.